# Configuring transactional replication with updatable subscription via SSMS 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms

Can I configure transactional replication with updatable subscription via SSMS 2012 (SQL Server 2012)? Is this removed from SSMS 2012 or I'm just missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updatable subscription is deprecated.

If you still want to implement it, you have to use T-SQL. You wont be able to do it using GUI.

See [Updatable Subscriptions for Transactional Replication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151718.aspx) and [Deprecated Features in SQL Server Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143550%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Ok. Thanks. So it's just removed from SSMS 2012

Comment: @NikolaD Yes, but as BOL mentions you should **avoid** using it as its going to go away.